# Multiple where clause for 2 column

Tags: sql, oracle

My table structure is like this:

```
sch_id  daynum  sched_hrs
123        1        7
123        2        6.5
123        3        5
456        1        8
456        2        4
456        3        3
```

I want to create a query which will get me the all the schedule `where
daynum = 1 and sched_hrs = 7 and daynum = 2 and sched_hrs = 6.5`.

I am trying this approach, but not getting any luck with it

```
select distinct sch_id from table
  where (daynum,sched_hrs) in (('1', '7')) and (daynum,sched_hrs) in (('2','6.5')) .
```

Comment: By editing your question, I've noticed that you can't have `daynum = 1 and` ... `and daynum = 2`. Aren't you looking for `where (daynum = 1 and sched_hrs = 7) or (daynum = 2 and sched_hrs = 6.5)` instead ?

Comment: I would recommend doing some reading on how to write SQL.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the correct result:

```
select sch_id from table t1 join t2 on t1.sch_id  =t2.sch_id  
  where t1.daynum =1 and t1.sched_hrs = 7 and t2.daynum =2 and t2.sched_hrs = 6.5
```

Comment: No. Actually I want a query which checks for (daynum =1 and sched_hrs = 7) and (daynum =2 and sched_hrs = 6.5)

Means on day 1 where sch_hrs is 7 and on day 2 where sch_hrs is 6.5

Comment: @Mohit have changed my answer. PLease take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Given your various comment, it seems that you are in fact searching for a `"sch_id"` having both a `sched_hrs` of 7 the first day, and a `sched_hrs` of 6.5 the second day.

If it's so, you might solve that using a self-join:

```
SELECT "sch_id" FROM T t1 JOIN T t2 USING("sch_id")
WHERE t1."daynum" = 1 AND t1."sched_hrs" = 7
  AND t2."daynum" = 2 AND t2."sched_hrs" = 6.5
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59631/1/0

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is an `OR`:

```
 WHERE ( daynum = 1 AND sched_hrs = 7 ) OR ( daynum = 2 AND sched_hrs = 6.5 )
```

I've used parentheses in the above even though they're not absolutely necessary in this case (`AND` takes precedence over `OR`).

You might also use `IN` (should give the same result):

```
WHERE (daynum, sched_hrs) IN ( (1, 7), (2, 6.5) )
```

Comment: I too think the same, so +1 to your answer.

Comment: That was my first thought to. But in fact the OP posted a comment saying it wasn't what he needed. See the comment on Jeans answer. As of now, this is quite nebulous, for me at least...

Comment: Agreed, nebulous. I think the OP is using "and" because he wants *both*, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try;

```
  select sch_id
from table
   where daynum in (1, 2)
 and sched_hrs in (7, 6.5)
```

Comment: Tried this

  select sch_id
from table
   where daynum in (1, 2)
 and sched_hrs in (7, 6.5)


but not getting the correct result.


Query suggested by Jens is giving the correct result but for my requirement I have to apply the join for 7 time (7 days of week).

So the performance of query is very high.

If there is any other approach for this?

Comment: 'in' faster than multiple 'or'. using 'in' is more efficient. Also I read your suggestion than answer your question. But i did not see @Mohit's editting answer. Sorry.

Comment: `'in' faster than multiple 'or'. using 'in' is more efficient` - Not always, check the explain plan

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * from test where daynum=1 and sched_hrs = 7 and sch_id in (select sch_id from test where daynum=1 )
union
select * from test where daynum=2 and sched_hrs = 6.5 and sch_id in (select sch_id from test where daynum=2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this:

```
select * from t t1 where daynum=1 and sched_hrs = 7 and 
exists (select 1 from t where sch_id = t1.sch_id and daynum=2 and sched_hrs = 6.5)
union all
select * from t t1 where daynum=2 and sched_hrs = 6.5 and 
exists (select 1 from t where sch_id = t1.sch_id and daynum=1 and sched_hrs = 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, a simple UNION would grab all the records you are looking for:

```
select sch_id,daynum,sched_hrs from table where daynum = '1' and sched_hrs = '7'
union
select sch_id,daynum,sched_hrs from table where daynum = '2' and sched_hrs = '6.5';
```